# Printing vs Returning function for a dictionary

Tags: python

I have the following two codes, similar except one function prints, while another returns the keys in a dictionary.

My question is, why does the one that returns, only show the first line when the print is called on the function?

```
**VERSION 1**
ColourOfCats = {"timmy":"black","sam":"white","john":"green"}

def catsfunc (dict):
    for i in dict.keys():
        return (i)

X = catsfunc(ColourOfCats)

print (X)

**VERSION 2**
ColourOfCats = {"timmy":"black","sam":"white","john":"green"}

def catsfunc (dict):
    for i in dict.keys():
        print (i)

catsfunc(ColourOfCats)
```

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: You can only return from a function once. (If it helps, you can think of `return` as setting the return value and exiting the function.)

Comment: @Ryan thank you. does this mean that if/while loops in a function never uses return (unless at the end), and only uses print?

from what I understand, we use return to store the value, while print just displays it without storing right?

Comment: that depends if you use `x = my_func()` then it will store value in `x` but if you directly use `print(my_func())`  returned value passed as argument of print function and that value will be printed in console but it isn't stored anywhere

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because a function can only return once.

> The return statement terminates the execution of a function and
>   returns control to the calling function. Execution resumes in the
>   calling function at the point immediately following the call.

So in your **VERSION 1** at line 8 when it return the `i` then return statement terminates the execution of a function and it so `for loop` doesn't go for second iteration for next value of dict.keys().

If you want to return all the result then never return iterator , instead store the output in a `list` , `dict` , `set` etc and at last return that 
Here is an example for you:

```
ColourOfCats = {"timmy":"black","sam":"white","john":"green"}

def catsfunc (dict):
    result=[]
    for i in dict.keys():
        result.append(i)  #instead of return here , store the output to a list
    return result         #now return 

X = catsfunc(ColourOfCats)

print (X)
```

output:

```
['timmy', 'john', 'sam']
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use `return` statement in function function will return the value and stops the execution and return control flow to calling line; hence even if you use for loop; when function returns first value another loops aren't executing whereas when you use `print` it is just printing the statement which is not causing to break the function flow.

However you can make generator function using `yield` keyword as below:

```
ColourOfCats = {"timmy":"black","sam":"white","john":"green"}

def catsfunc (dict):
    for i in dict.keys():
        yield i

X = catsfunc(ColourOfCats)  # X is now generator object

for items in X:  # iterate generator object
    print (items)
```